# using Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace in mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, replace, absolute-path

I am using Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace to replace some words from the url path ,

```
 string blogUrl = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("/rss", string.Empty).TrimEnd("/".ToCharArray());//This line replaces rss
 blogUrl = blogUrl.Replace("/articles/articles","/articles");//This line doesnt replace articles
```

You can check the rss feed by clicking on rss image on the right side of the website :[Rss](http://www.dotraining.co.uk/articles)
. 
The link Rss feed generating is :

```
http://www.dotraining.co.uk/articles/articles/blog/basketball-posts/guada-highlights/
```

instead of`http://www.dotraining.co.uk/articles/blog/basketball-posts/guada-highlights/`

Any ideas where i m getting it wrong

Comment: Why are you using string.replace to manipulate urls instead of using the routes and url helpers?

Comment: Coz i dunno which url helper to use :)

Comment: that will depend on what you are trying to achieve but `Url.Action` seems like a good candidate.

Comment: u mean i should use something like Url.Action().replace

Comment: absolutely not. You should not use any replace. You should only use Url.Action.

Answer (score 2):

Try escaping the / character in the string:

```
blogUrl = blogUrl.Replace("articles//articles","articles");
```

Or try using string literals for it:

```
blogUrl = blogUrl.Replace(@"/articles/articles",@"/articles");
```

Comment: Never use string manipulation such as replace, ... to manipulate urls. There are much better ways.

Comment: I updated my answer. I think I may have confused forward slash with backslash. I do have to agree that you probably shouldn't use replace for URL manipulations.